# How to load classes from target instead of from jar in maven pom

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-plugin

We have a multi module maven project where previously we load our classes from a jar dependency as below

```
<plugin>   
  <groupId>xxxx<groupId>
  <artifactId>xxx<artificatId>
  <version>xxx</version>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>yyyy<groupId>
     <artifactId>yyyy<artificatId>
     <version>yyy</version>
    </dependency>
    .
    .
  </dependencies>
 </plugin>
```

Now due to business requirement,

1. I want remove dependency (yyyy) and use that dependency code as part
   of project/src folder
2. No more dependency used -- business condition
   3.. Plugin XXX has to load classes from project/target of project.

Issue here is when plugin xxx is running it is looking for classes which are defined as dependency but not from project target folder.

Please suggest how to proceed ?

Comment: Test classes are not exported in a normal jar, but you can create a new artifact with the test classes in it.  That will require you to change the Pom of plug-in xx.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen edited post with more meaningful information. I cant use another dependency as it is business enforced condition.

Comment: You may want to add the business requirement.  Also if you cannot change xx you have very few possibilities

Comment: it can be depend on what plugin xxx you use and what for plugin needs classes from dependencies, some plugins have options like add class paths ...

Comment: Why has a dependency needed to be specified for using a plugin? Can you explain that more in detail?

Comment: Did you try to do something like [this](https://maven.apache.org/plugins-archives/maven-checkstyle-plugin-2.4/examples/multi-module-config.html) ?

Comment: It does not make sense to have a "business requirement" not to use any dependency. You  (or your boss) have certainly misunderstood something.